# Origin of the phrase "on the wrong side of history"

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

I've been hearing the phrase "on the wrong side of history" a lot lately, most recently today when [President Obama said](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/mar/03/russian-sanctions-likely-putin-ukraine-crimea) that Russia was on "the wrong side of history" for its actions in Ukraine.

There is already a [question about the meaning of the phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15987/49773), but I'm wondering about the origin.  When was this phrase first used, and where did it come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of the phrase "the wrong side of history"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15987/meaning-of-the-phrase-the-wrong-side-of-history) There probably *is* no meaningful "origin" for such a trivial turn of phrase - and if there was, it should be on that earlier question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Ngram,

[image: n-gram]

the phrase first appeared in books in 1935, disappeared until 1949, and experienced an early spike in usage around 1951. A spike reaching a slightly lower peak occurred in 1967, followed by intermittent but generally up-trending popularity until reaching another high point in 1985. A slight drop-off then was followed by a sharp increase from the early 90s up to a historical high in 2000, the last year of Google's Ngram-available data.

It seems the first use noted was in [The American Spectator, Volume 3, Issue 34](http://tinyurl.com/nak7aou):

> The editorial bears the heading, "McDonald and Lenin," and he Times
>   puts itself on the wrong side of history thus: "If the British people
>   regard the advent of Labor Socialists without alarm, on reason is that
>   they know that they have to deal with a Labor government soberly aware
>   of its limitations and its responsibilities...The example of Russia is
>   a virtual guarantee against any tendency on the part..."

Whether the phrase originated with the author of this piece is not evident.

This version of the same Ngram of the phrase “on the wrong side of history” with a "[smoothing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info)" of 50, shows the general trend over time from 1800 to 2000.
[image]

Comment: Since I can't seem to isolate the source for any of the charted uses aside from the first, I'm not positive I'm correct about that one either.

Comment: If you didn't already know, you can go direct to [Google Books](http://books.google.com/) and set a date range there. The three entries before 1935 are all irrelevant contexts - your 1935 citation is the first matching OP's usage. But I think the whole question (and OP's *specific* version) are trivial issues. The usage **history is on our side** goes back *much* further. It's really just an ordinary expression, apart from figuratively casting inanimate/abstract "history" as an "ally".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I thought that's what I was doing, but I kept not getting any results for time periods that the Ngram showed I should get results. I'm obviously doing something wrong, and I'm terribly sleep-deprived right now, so I doubt I'll figure out my mistake tonight.

Comment: Try setting "smoothing" to 1 and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, great point about **history is on our side**. I am reminded of the idea that there is a great and oft ignored difference between **God is on our side**, and, **We are on God's side**.

Comment: Indeed. One obvious difference being that if your enemies don't believe in your god, they're not going to care much if he's on your side or not. But if they think you're on *God's* side, they might be more worried because they'll think you're fanatics who might disregard "earthly" considerations such as the Geneva Convention.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean to help find the specific book's referenced? I set the smoothing to 0 so that I could see the exact years for the occurrences. What am I missing? (Much I'm sure, as my only experience with Ngrams has been here on ELU--specifically, iirc, thanks to your posting them!)

Comment: You used to be able to "drill down" to the actual indexed instances by daterange in NGrams, but they've stopped that now (dunno why), so you need Google Books for that. Incidentally, remember NGrams is case-sensitive and limited to five words in a term - but it does index apostrophes and "parts of speech", unlike Books. So the two systems aren't directly comparable.

Comment: Something tells me the down-vote on my answer was meant as an "Answering off topic questions "demerit". Yet, the question stands, so it seems like the "demerit" should not.

Comment: Well, my "closevote" for it as a duplicate has expired now, and obviously even if anyone else agreed with me at the time, there weren't enough of us to effect the closure. I hadn't personally cast any up/downvotes on this page - but I must admit now I can see it below my typing area, I will upvote Kris's answer right after I hit "Add Comment".  Someone might simply have felt more strongly than me that it's pointless using NGrams to identify a "first use" for such a trivial reworking of a standard expression (or they're even more liberal than me with their downvotes! :)

Comment: Yeah, who knowsm FF? The down-vote without explanatory comment fails to instruct. Not sure whether you mean it's pointless to _ask_ about the first use of a "trivial reworking of a standard expression" or that the NGram provides no useful info on the matter. If the latter, can you be more specific as to why? In what sort of cases do you see Ngrams as useful? I've searched SO meta, but have not found any related discussions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did find some meta discussions regarding the used of Ngrams here, but found no strong conclusions. Also, I thought I'd just forgotten how to "drill down" to the actual indexed instances by daterange in NGrams, or that they'd changed how to do it. They become far less useful if one can't delve into the data to examine examples.

Comment: I think they probably had technical problems with the "drill-down" facility - it never honoured whatever corpus might be selected, and it would often say "no results found" in the detail screen for a date "sub-range" where it claimed results on the chart. I find NGrams is better for showing trends with common usages - if you want specific citations for rarer collocations, or earliest use, you need Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

It's no more than a clever take on the very well-known idiom: *on the wrong side of the law* / *on the wrong side of someone*.

I could say *on the wrong side of* ([an expression limited to my imagination](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=nF8VU9-4BuPriAeBmoCYCg&ved=0CBoQ1S4#q=%22on%20the%20wrong%20side%20of%22%20-law%20-history))

See also the [bare idiom](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-on-the-wrong-side-of).